# Python code cutting off part of word from list

Tags: python

This code is cutting off apart of a word in my list. Does anyone know why?

```
# setup the book list
master_book_list = []

# read in the file and store as a list
def read_file():
    global master_book_list
    infile = open("bookdata.txt", 'r')

    # reading each line of the file and putting details of the books into a list of lists
    for row in infile:
        book_details = []
        start_pos = 0
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            for index in range(len(row)):
                if row [index] == ',' or index == len(row) -1:
                    book_details.append(row[start_pos:index].strip())
                    start_pos = index + 1

            master_book_list.append(book_details)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to split a line wherever there are commas and `row.split(',')` will do exactly that. You should also include an example of your input file where the problem arises.

Comment: What is your input, output and expected output? What is the problem?

Comment: Retl34 has the correct answer to your needs. The problem in your code is most likely the `index == len(row) -1` check. The subsequent statement will append the last segment minus the last character (`row[start_pos:index]` corresponds to `ros[start_pos:len(row)-1]`)

Comment: What @Kendas wrote, sounds reasonable. If it doesn't solve your problem, maybe you could add some examples of input, actual output and desired output. Then maybe a good debugger can help you to find answers to questions like this. If you use an IDE like spyder, it's worth checking how the debugger can be started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a comma separated list of items in your file. I would suggest rather than manually searching, to do a split on the list. If this is actually a csv file. I would recommend using the `csv` python library instead of manually parsing.

```
def read_file():
    global master_book_list
    #Updated to the preferred 'with open'
    with open("bookdata.txt", 'r') as infile:
        # reading each line of the file and putting details of the books into a list of lists
        for row in infile:
            if not row.startswith('#'):
                book_details = [item.strip() for item in row.split(',')]
                master_book_list.append(book_details)
```

Further, what you should probably do the make the code cleaner is this and call it by `read_file(master_book_list, 'bookdata.txt')`

```
def read_file(masterBookList, filename):
    #Updated to the preferred 'with open'
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        # reading each line of the file and putting details of the books into a list of lists
        for row in infile:
            if not row.startswith('#'):
                masterBookList.append([item.strip() for item in row.split(',')])
```

Comment: Might as well get rid of that global statement and return `master_book_list` from the function.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure how far to reduce the original code. Added a cleaner version. Thanks @Reti43

Comment: Thanks so much guys